# Backtick in appending result is not working in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am appending html result to div id using .html in my file.

```
<html>
 <head> Title
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body> 
  <div id="static-content"></div>
   <p>test</p>

   <script>
   $(document).ready(function($){  

      $('#static-content').html(`<div class="test-class"><p>Test paragraph</p></div>`);

}); 
</script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

The back tick is not working on Only on IE browser. IS any fix available for this issue?

Please anyone share your thoughts . Thanks

Comment: FWIW your end " is probably in the wrong place. Looks like it should read `<div class="test-class">.....</div>` rather than `<div class="test-class>......</div>"`.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley, yes i forgot it, i edited my question now

Comment: In this particular case, just don't use back-tick, it's not doing anything for you..  just using single quote instead.

Comment: IE does not support that relatively new JavaScript syntax. In your case, you don't really need it anyway.

Comment: @Keith, I have posted the sample html there, actually i need to append html that have single quote as well as double quote

Comment: @Pointy, is any fix available for this issue?

Comment: No, there is no way to fix it because the IE11 JavaScript parser simply does not recognize that syntax. You can of course escape embedded quote characters without resorting to back-tick syntax, which is what everybody did for many years prior to the introduction of the new syntax.

Comment: The other possibility, as others have noted, is to introduce a preprocessor (Babel) into your build process to translate newer JavaScript features into JavaScript compatible with older environments like IE11.

Comment: @pointy, can you pls update me, how to escape that, because I have HTML of around 50 lines, which includes ' and " also..

Comment: @pointy, can you update me either of the way, I am not cleared with your comment

Comment: Pick either `'` or `"` to quote the HTML, and then use backslash to escape the quote characters.\

Answer (score 4):

Backticks are for Template Literals and unfortunately they're not supported by IE11 (assuming that's what you're using).

You could use a transpiler like Babel that will convert the template literal into the ECMAScript 5 syntax in order to be understood by IE11. If you'd like you could use other browsers that support them, but it's up to you. I'd stick to ' and " instead.

Comment: this answer i seen before posting my question, is any fix available?

Comment: I updated my answer with a line at the end. I'd stick with ' and " for now.

Comment: I have posted sample HTML, Actually the content I am appending which has ' and ", then ur solution will break the HTML, it won't work, I have already tried

Comment: Did you try this: `$('#static-content').html('<div class="test-class"><p>Test paragraph</p></div>');` ? It's working for me [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/gy7bqmfh/)

Comment: I have long HTML with new lines, with single quote and all, it will break the html

Comment: @jafarpinjar but you can easily quote the quote characters as necessary with the backslash; why is that so hard?

Comment: @pointy, no, I am getting that content form php using file get contents and storing in variable of js, then appending it to div I'd

Comment: Then include it in the JavaScript by JSON-encoding the strings.

Answer (score 1):

For many years prior to the introduction of back-tick templates, it's been possible to produce HTML in JavaScript. Quote characters can be embedded in strings by escaping them with the backslash character:

```
$('#static-content').html('<div class="test-class"><p>Test paragraph</p></div>');
```

works for your simple case, and

```
$("#static-content").html("div class=\"test-class\"><p>Test paragraph</p></div>");
```

also works.

Comment: pls understand I can't use ' or ", because the content I am appending already have, those elements so, it will break

Comment: So change your content!  Literally everybody in the world who included HTML from JavaScript has been doing that for *years*.

Comment: The content is auto generated from php script, I can not edit every time

Comment: Then use PHP to fix the quotes; that's what `json_encode()` does

Comment: that means, I am getting content to php variable, as $php_content = file_get_contents('test.php'); then json_encode(php_content); may resolve this issue?

Comment: I tried json encode, this throwing me inalid character error in console